# How to add reference to another table column as foreignKey in the migration using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In my Node API, I'm using the ORM Sequuilize and trying to understand how to make the migration file in this way to tables is referred to as each other by a foreign key.

I have a Student who HasMany Projects and Projects BelongTo one student.

So my models are like this:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Student = sequelize.define("Student", {
        _id: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            //autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        dateOfBirth: {
            type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
            allowNull: false
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });

    Student.associate = function(models) {
        Student.hasMany(models.Project, {
            foreignKey: 'student_id',
            as: 'projects',
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
          });
    };
    return Student;
};
```

Project model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Project = sequelize.define("Project", {
        project_id: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            //autoIncrement: true
        },
        student_id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        },
        creationDate: {
            type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
            allowNull: true
        },
        repoUrl: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        },
        liveUrl: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });

    Student.associate = function(models) {
        Project.belongsTo(models.Student, {
            foreignKey: "student_id",
            as: "student",
            onDelete: "CASCADE"
        });
    };
    return Student;
};
```

My migration as follows but as I stated before I don't know how to include the foreign key and the way I did does not work, the migration is created but in the DB the relationship is not made:

Student migration

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable("Students", {
            _id: {
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.UUID,
                defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
                //autoIncrement: true
            },
            name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            email: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT,
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true
            },
            dateOfBirth: {
                type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
                allowNull: false
            },
            createdAt: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                allowNull: false
            },
            updatedAt: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                allowNull: false
            }
        });
    },

    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable("Students");
    }
};
```

Project migration

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable("Projects", {
            project_id: {
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.UUID,
                defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
                //autoIncrement: true
            },
            student_id: {
                foreignKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.UUID,
                defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
                allowNull: false
            },
            name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true
            },
            description: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT,
                allowNull: true
            },
            creationDate: {
                type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
                allowNull: true
            },
            repoUrl: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT,
                allowNull: true
            },
            liveUrl: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT,
                allowNull: true
            },
            createdAt: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                allowNull: false
            },
            updatedAt: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                allowNull: false
            }
        });
    },

    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable("Projects");
    }
};
```

Comment: First of all you can start without sequelize-cli that will make things easier for you ! 


these migrations are for model generation now you will have to create new migration and modify relactions in that migration file

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, what I want to achieve is how to make the migration with the relationship. I have to use Sequelize as part of my requirements and with the cli. 
I need to know how can I make a migration file which allows creating the relationships.

Comment: i have you repo i will update you once i have all steps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the migration workflow:

1. Generate models and migration files using `sequelize-cli`.
2. Define the association between `Student` and `Project` based on your business requirements.
3. Based on the associations between the models, modify the migration files, add the foreign keys(add `student_id` column to `Project` table). For your case, `Project` table has a `student_id` column as its foreign key reference to the `Student` table's `_id` column.

Here is the working example:

`models/student.js`:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Student = sequelize.define('Student', {
    _id: {
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    dateOfBirth: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });

  Student.associate = function(models) {
    Student.hasMany(models.Project, {
      foreignKey: 'student_id',
      as: 'projects',
    });
  };
  return Student;
};
```

`models/project.js`:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Project = sequelize.define('Project', {
    project_id: {
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    creationDate: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    repoUrl: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    liveUrl: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });

  Project.associate = function(models) {
    Project.belongsTo(models.Student, {
      foreignKey: 'student_id',
      as: 'student',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    });
  };
  return Project;
};
```

`migrations/20200213113039-create-student.js`:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Students', {
      _id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      dateOfBirth: {
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Students');
  },
};
```

`migrations/20200213113231-create-project.js`:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Projects', {
      project_id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      },
      student_id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        references: {
          model: {
            tableName: 'Students',
          },
          key: '_id',
        },
        allowNull: false,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      description: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      creationDate: {
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      repoUrl: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      liveUrl: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Projects');
  },
};
```

After executing the command `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`, check the table information in the database(I also created seed file to insert some demo data):

```js
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "Students";
                 _id                  |     name      |          email           | dateOfBirth |           createdAt           |           updatedAt
--------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 2c6db3cb-82c7-4728-a259-23520bd760d0 | Rosalind Mohr | Natasha.Littel@gmail.com | 2020-02-13  | 2020-02-13 12:39:23.508379+00 | 2020-02-13 12:39:23.508379+00
(1 row)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "Projects";
              project_id              | name  | description | creationDate | repoUrl | liveUrl |           createdAt           |           updatedAt           |              student_id
--------------------------------------+-------+-------------+--------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 b271060c-bd20-48f4-a8a5-65508b99cfbf | nobis |             |              |         |         | 2020-02-13 12:39:23.540054+00 | 2020-02-13 12:39:23.540054+00 | 2c6db3cb-82c7-4728-a259-23520bd760d0
(1 row)
```

Describe the tables:

```js
node-sequelize-examples=# \d "Students";
              Table "public.Students"
   Column    |           Type           | Modifiers
-------------+--------------------------+-----------
 _id         | uuid                     | not null
 name        | character varying(255)   | not null
 email       | text                     | not null
 dateOfBirth | date                     | not null
 createdAt   | timestamp with time zone | not null
 updatedAt   | timestamp with time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "Students_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (_id)
    "Students_email_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
Referenced by:
    TABLE ""Projects"" CONSTRAINT "Projects_student_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES "Students"(_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE

node-sequelize-examples=# \d "Projects";
               Table "public.Projects"
    Column    |           Type           | Modifiers
--------------+--------------------------+-----------
 project_id   | uuid                     | not null
 name         | character varying(255)   | not null
 description  | text                     |
 creationDate | date                     |
 repoUrl      | text                     |
 liveUrl      | text                     |
 createdAt    | timestamp with time zone | not null
 updatedAt    | timestamp with time zone | not null
 student_id   | uuid                     |
Indexes:
    "Projects_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (project_id)
    "Projects_name_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "Projects_student_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES "Students"(_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I believe that you want to delete all projects of a user when the user is deleted.